# How to get all the parameters names of a Get Request (from query string)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I have an asp.net application and I get each parameter individually. Like this.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request["bet_transaction_id"]
```

Because the paraemeter list in the get request is unpredictable, I need a way to get them and their associated values dynamically.
How can I achieve so?

**UPDATE - Working solution.**

```
     Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var queryKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString)
            {
                
                queryParams.Add(queryKey.ToString(), HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryKey.ToString()]);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string,string> queryParams=  new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var queryKey in Request.Query.Keys)
{
     queryParams.Add(queryKey, Request.Query[queryKey]);
}
```

Comment: The code didnt compile but your solution was close enough.